# ManyToMany entity relation: set a default value in a field form by the value of the current user using FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

In my Symfony project I am using the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

When a user is connected, I can collect his informations like this:

```
$user=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();
$user=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getEmail();
/* ...etc */
```

This is my user entity:

```
class Users extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Parcs", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_parcs",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parc_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $parcs;

    /**
     * Get parcs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getParcs()
    {
        return $this->parcs;
    }

    /**
     * Set parcs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function setParcs($parcs)
    {
        return $this->parcs;
    }
```

As you can see, I add an other **ManyToMany** relation in my user class, `$parcs`.

This my parc entity:

```
class Parcs
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="parcs")
     */
    private $users;

//rest of my entity attributes, object, properties etc

// getters and setters

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * Set users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function setUsers($users)
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
```

Now in a twig view, only if the user is connected can add a parc. If I am connected I can have access to the `addingParcAction()`. This my controller method:

```
public function addParcsAction() {

    // get the current username
    $user=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $parc = new Parcs;

    $form=$this->createForm(new ParcsType($user), $parc);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid())) {

            $form->bind($request);
            $parc = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($parc);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myView'));
        }

    else {
            return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:addParcs.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
         }
}
```

Everything works well except the principal: no data are persisted in my user field. In fact, the new parc is registered, but my entity fiedl user is empty.

Only one user can add a parc at time, but many users can be associated with this parc (this is made in an admin view, nothing to do with this problem). **How can I persit the relation like this:**

> I retrieve the current user, and then when I want to add a parc, the
>   entity field user is automatically filled with his username I retrieved by the security.context method.

---

EDIT

I have also tried this solution in my controller:

```
public function addParcsAction() {

    // get the current username
    $currentUser=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $parc = new Parcs;

    $form=$this->createForm(new ParcsType(), $parc);
    $form->get('users')->setData($currentUser);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid())) {

            $form->bind($request);
            $parc = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($parc);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myView'));
        }

    else {
            return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:addParcs.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
         }
}
```

And this time I have this error occured:

> Unable to transform value for property path "users": Expected a
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to declare properties parcs and users as ArrayCollection in the constructors, as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata). Try this :

```
class Users extends BaseUser
{
    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->parcs = new ArrayCollection();
        // your own logic
    }
```

And:

```
class Parcs
{
    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Comment: indeed I forgot the `public function __construct()`, but it changes nothing when I persist the data in the form, the problem is still the same.

Comment: see my edit in my initial post, I have tried something different. I think I need to proceed differently with a ManyToMany relation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setUsers()` method in the Parcs entity acts as a getter instead of a setter. Since it is a *toMany relationship, delete it and add an `addUser()` method instead:

```
/**
 * Add user
 * @return Parcs
 */
public function addUser($user)
{
    $this->users[] = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

Then use this method to add the user to the Parcs in the controller.

```
...
$currentUser = $this->getUser();

$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$parc = new Parcs();
$parc->addUser($currentUser);

$form=$this->createForm(new ParcsType(), $parc);
...
```